# How to get previous value if entered value in cell of grid is removed

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell-formatting

I have one data grid with 3 columns item_name, price and remarks.When I entered price in cell of grid and press tab then it's total is calculated by  using datagrid_cellValueChange event. Now if I removed price and entered new value then how will I get the updated value?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to store the previews value as property of each object in your data source list.
and you have to detect when the cell edit end to put the current value to the previews and put the new value to the current.

example :

```
Class A
{
public string PreviewsValue{ get; set; }
public string CurrentValue{ get; set; }
}
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this without event handling.

Assuming your datagridview is **bound** to a **datatable** you can add a **computed column** that will perform the calculation automatically.

Here is some Microsoft documentation about it: [DataColumn.Expression Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8)

Consider posting some code so we can assist further.

Comment: My gridview is not bound to datatable

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both of you . I have got my answer. I have used datagrid_CellEntered event .